# how to get uploaded file from one page to another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to get uploaded file from one page to another page and then save to my online server.

My Code is

First Page:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:3132/Sample/api/Test.aspx?frm=31" method="post" target="_blank">
  Name: <input type="text" name="f1" id="f1"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  FileName: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Page:Entries.aspx

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dtData=new System.Data.DataTable();

        foreach (string strKey in Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {
            if(strKey.Equals("data.xml") || dtData.Columns.Contains(strKey))
                continue;
            dtData.Columns.Add(strKey);

            System.Data.DataRow dr=dtData.NewRow();
            if(dtData.Rows.Count>0)
                dr=dtData.Rows[0];
            dr[strKey]=Request.Form[strKey];
            if(dtData.Rows.Count<1)
                dtData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        string strFileName = string.Empty;
        string newFilename = string.Empty;
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/APIUploaded"),     Request.Params["filename"].ToString());
        newFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        System.IO.FileInfo fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
        newFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", newFilename, fInfo.Extension);
       strFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/APIUploaded"),   newFilename);
        using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(strFileName))
            {
            /*Getting stream from the Request object.*/
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                int byteStreamLength = (int)stream.Length;
                byte[] byteStream = new byte[byteStreamLength];
                /*Reading the stream to a byte array.*/
                stream.Read(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
                /*Writing the byte array to the harddisk.*/
                fileStream.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
            }

    }
```

Through the second page I am getting form values with uploaded file name. When I am going to save to my Online server folder, the file contents are empty. Is this possible to get uploaded file from one page to another page by using file upload control in asp.net?

Comment: you're not going to be uploading any files with a missing `enctype` on that form.

Comment: @Marc B, Thanks a lot. I corrected my form tag. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the enctype to the form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3132/GoLeadsUpdate/api/Entries.aspx?frm=31" 
    method="post" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
.
.
.
</form>
```

And I think you have to look at `Request.Files`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This one helped me to figure out my problem. Thanks a lot.